# Entity Framework - MVC 4 - Repository Architecture

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering if someone could give me some input on my repository code and make any suggestions on how I might improve the code? Below I will include the repository class and the controller. Also, if I wanted to insert a value at the top of the list, what is a nice way to do that?

```
    public static List<ChartApp> ListApplications()
    {
        using (var db = new LatencyDBContext())
        {
            var appNames = db.LoginApplications.Select(item => new ChartApp()
              {
                  LoginApplicationID = item.LoginApplicationID,
                  LoginAppName = item.LoginAppName,
              });
            return appNames.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And, the controller:

```
    var listApps = LoginApplicationRepository.ListApplications().OrderBy(item => item.LoginAppName);

        var myCharts = new ChartsViewModel();
        myCharts.AppsForChart = listApps.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the structure of the code looks fine to me, the OrderBy could be done in the repository - especially if the listing should normally be ordered by LoginAppName. There isn't a need to call ToList() on listApps in the controller as this has already been done in the repository so listApps is already a list.

To insert an item at the start of the list use the Insert method, eg:

```
listApps.Insert(0, newAppItem);
```